# is thread 1: signal SIGABRT always a connection issue (cgimagedestinationfinalize)

Tags: swift, cgimage

Using this block, my App is crashing everytime it tries to

```
CGImageDestinationFinalize(gifDest!)
```

block

```
func createGIF(with images: [CGImage], data: Data, loopCount: Int, frameDelay: Double) -> Data {
    print("()createGIF.HandHistoryTableVC")
    let gifDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data as! CFMutableData, kUTTypeGIF, images.count, nil)
    let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: loopCount]]
    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(gifDest!, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)
    let frameProperties = [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String): [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String): frameDelay]]
    for img in images {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(gifDest!, img, frameProperties as CFDictionary?)
    }
    print("GIF in Progress")
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(gifDest!)
    print("gifMade")
    return data;
}
```

Error Report

[image]
I'm lost to the reason for this crash. All research about "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" seems to say it's a connection problem, but my whole App works fine if i comment out the CGImageDestinationFinalize()

Comment: The error message says you are trying to append data to an immutable (NSData) object. Generally type casting to a mutable (Core)Foundation type doesn't work in Swift. Most of the `signal SIGABRT` errors are the attempt to unwrap `nil`.

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557)

Comment: thank you i will edit my post immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func createGIF(with images: [CGImage], data: CFMutableData, loopCount: Int, frameDelay: Double) -> Data {
    print("()createGIF.HandHistoryTableVC")
    let gifDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(data, kUTTypeGIF, images.count, nil)
    let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: loopCount]]
    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(gifDest!, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)
    let frameProperties = [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String): [(kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String): frameDelay]]
    for img in images {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(gifDest!, img, frameProperties as CFDictionary?)
    }
    print("GIF in Progress")
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(gifDest!)
    print("gifMade")
    return data as Data;
}
```

with CFMutableData initializer

```
CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
```

solved this issue.